# Recuperar archivos eliminados de forma irreversible GIT - Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, vscode

Hola a todos! Necesito su ayuda, he eliminado todos mis archivos de mi carpeta local desde Visual studio code. Lo he realizado desde el panel de control de git, tenia todos los archivos seleccionados y pense que solo los eliminaría de VSC. Me ha salido un mensaje que la acción era irreversible e igual continue. Les adjunto captura de los output con los codigos que se ejecutaron para borrar mis archivos. no habia hecho ningun commit anteriormente ni tengo backup de la carpeta. Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de volver atras la accion. Muchas gracias desde ya!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *"Irreversible"* y *"recuperar"* no suelen ir juntos en la misma frase por un motivo concreto. Si algo es irreversible pero se puede revertir... no sería irreversible. Si no hay un commit previo y te cargaste los archivos, están perdidos. Es como si los hubieses borrado de tu disco duro manualmente. Lo bueno de hacer dos veces las cosas es que se aprende el triple. Dos veces haciéndolo y una al saber lo que no se debe hacer :)

Comment: Lo que no pasó por un commit se fue al hoyo negro de tu compu.

Comment: Si por lo menos hiciste un `git add` y el repositorio todavía existe, podrías buscar entre los _dangling objects_ para buscar el _tree_ de la raíz del árbol que estaba en el index que mejor represente el estado del proyecto. No es sencillo, pero si hiciste `git add` y se agregó algo al index, es posible. Déjame buscar alguna referencia.

Comment: Podrías indicar la salida de `git status` del repositorio? De pronto está todo en el índice (insisto, si no borraste el repositorio) y se podría usar `git restore` para ponerlo en el árbol de trabajo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git

Comment: @eftshift0 No llegué a realizar ninguna acción de los archivos por git, cuando solicito status me indica lo siguiente. On branch master

No commits yet

Comment: La unica alternativa será intentar recuperarlos mediante un programa de recovery de archivos. Agradezco a todos sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que hicieras un commit o agregaras los archivos a un repositorio, aún se pueden recuperar.

1. En caso de que se eliminó desde el repositorio:

```
git checkout <hash-commit>
```

es el número de hash del commit en donde posiblemente encuentres el archivo.

2. Posiblemente, se podría lograr revirtiendo los cambios que hiciste:

```
git reset --soft
```

Te animo a que leas un poco más de la documentación sobre [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema recién, el "mismo", digo, si no te entendí mal.

Resolví "restaurar" los archivos eliminados de modo "irreversible", copiándolos del historial de la línea de tiempo a nuevos archivos con el mismo nombre.

Sólo fui abajo, en "LÍNEA DE TIEMPO", y allí, en los tres puntos, a "Historia local: buscar entrada para restaurar...", y allí me aparecieron todos los archivos borrados "irreversiblemente", en una ventada en VSC con nombre tachado y con un candado, pero que me permite ver el contenido y copiarlo, para "restaurarlo" manualmente, copiándolo de nuevo en nuevos archivos.

Espero te sirva esto, saludos. :)

PD: y eso que recién comienzo a estudiar programación (?